# Error running bfast function

Tags: r

This is probably obvious but I cannot see where the problem is. I’m trying to run bfast on a yearly time series to detect abrupt changes in trend but keep getting the following error (it is indeed the call to stl what is causing the problem):

```
bfast(GM85.ts,h=0.15,max.iter=1,season="none")

Error in stl(Yt, "periodic") :  series is not periodic or has less than two periods
```

My time series has frequency 1 and 95 years of data

```
GM85.ts
Time Series:
Start = 2006 
End = 2100 
Frequency = 1

 [1] 13.88868 13.89915 13.91431 13.93718 13.94067 13.94063 13.96324 13.99648 14.01391 14.03268 14.04667 14.05893 14.05230 14.06443 14.07909 14.11433 14.14736 14.14514 14.15454 14.19593 14.23417 14.23578 14.25171 14.27545 14.27213
[26] 14.29543 14.32851 14.34124 14.36091 14.38245 14.41517 14.42666 14.45183 14.49599 14.50378 14.52052 14.54298 14.58360 14.60798 14.62069 14.64962 14.68641 14.71247 14.72497 14.76606 14.79369 14.81297 14.84822 14.86503 14.89134
[51] 14.92601 14.95497 14.98318 15.01789 15.05929 15.09193 15.11453 15.14574 15.17960 15.20188 15.23737 15.27275 15.28612 15.32248 15.34883 15.38858 15.42155 15.45223 15.48342 15.51099 15.54076 15.58005 15.59959 15.63353 15.66272
[76] 15.69312 15.71358 15.73641 15.76502 15.79923 15.83983 15.87472 15.91833 15.93602 15.99177 16.03119 16.05529 16.07834 16.10982 16.14174 16.17376 16.22898 16.25100 16.27703 16.30971
```

Therefore it is periodic and has more than two periods… what is causing the error then?

Answer (score 1):

Seasonality only occurs when there is more than one observation per year.  bfast can't find a harmonic equation given a single value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `frequency` when you create the time series object using `ts()`. Example of data with six measurements per year:

```
mydata <- rep(c(1,4,6,8,5,2), 50) + rnorm(50*6)
plot(mydata, type = "l")
ts <- ts(mydata, frequency = 6, start = 1969)
```

Check by typing `ts`, that will give you:

```
Time Series:
Start = c(1969, 1) 
End = c(2018, 6) 
Frequency = 6
```